# Angular service can not be found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am trying to set up a simple service example for myself in angular and I am having trouble. The service should return Hello World then the controller should log it to the console.

The error is saying:

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ColorService due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ColorService' is not available!

What am I doing wrong here.

**Service.js**

```
var Service = angular.module('Service', []);

Service.service('Service', function() {
  function test(){
    return 'Hello World'
  }
}
```

**Main.js**

```
angular.module('iukapp', ['Service']).controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Service'];

function MainCtrl($scope, Service){
  console.log(Service.test());
}
```

Comment: Maybe you forgot to inject the script: `<script src="Service.js"></script>`. Here is a working example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w7NkViNAvRJDXhKp4BEu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your function to context of your service (this) and then it will be accessible: `this.test = function() {return "Hello world";};`

Comment: Still getting [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module Service due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'Service' is not available!

Comment: Do you load both script files in your index.html? Also be sure it is loaded in correct order. First angular library, then your service.js and last your main.js file

Comment: Yes I have   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.js"> </script>   
<script src="/controllers/Service.js"></script>   
<script src="/controllers/Main.js"></script>

Comment: @jrocc I believe the order matters, your `Service.js` should come **after** `Main.js`, otherwise it doesn't know where `Service` is injected from

Comment: Yes I just realized that it works now thank you for the help.